# Spring Boot Solr : Index List of child documents

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, solr, spring-data-solr

I am getting an XML of the below format which I want to index into Solr using SpringBoot. However, I get an exception when I try to index the parent `Document` with a `List` of `ChildDocuments`.

**XML** -

```
<EmployeeMaster xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Employee>
  <Name>Empolyee1</Name>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Department>
    <Name>Department1</Name>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </Department>
  <Department>
    <Name>Department1</Name>
    <ID>1</ID>
  </Department>
 </Employee>
</EmployeeMaster>
```

I have the following `Entity` -

**Employee.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "employee")
public class Employee implements IEmployee, Serializable {

  @Id
  @Field(ID_FIELD)
  private String id;
  @Field(NAME_FIELD)
  private String name;
  @Field(child = true)
  private Collection<Department> departments;
  @Field(ENTITY_TYPE_FIELD)
  private String entityType;

  public Employee(String id) {
    this.id = "EMP_" + id;
    this.entityType = "employee";
  }
}
```

**Deparment.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "employee")
public class Department implements IDepartment, Serializable {

  @Id
  @Field(ID_FIELD)
  private String id;
  @Field(NAME_FIELD)
  private String name;
  @Field(ENTITY_TYPE_FIELD)
  private String entityType;

  public Department(String id) {
    this.id = "DEP_" + id;
    this.entityType = "department";
  }
}
```

When I try to save this to the Solr using the `save` method from `SolrCrudRepository` class I get the following exception -

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: ERROR: [doc=EMP_1] unknown field 'departments'; 
nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: ERROR: [doc=EMP_1] unknown field 'departments'
```

The `Repository`, `EmployeeRepository` is just an interface which `extends` `SolrCrudRepository`.

In my `Service` class I am calling the `save` method from the `EmployeeRepository`.

**POM** -

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Solr schema** -

```
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="lower" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="entity_type" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: your solr schema doesn't have definition for department

Comment: The fields are common. What do you mean by definition? What is missing?

Comment: you have field definition in your schema file for each field in Employee class right? which tell solr about the type of ghe field(string, boolean or collection) and whether it needs to be stored and / or indexed. In the above schema you have mentioned, there is no entry for `departments`. hence Solr doesn't know how to create it or index it. That is exactly what the error message is saying `unknown field 'departments'`

Comment: The fields can be reused for `Nested` documents or `Child` documents. This is `Solr` internal and it works when I submit documents directly to Solr using update options from Solr. However, from the `Spring Boot` application I am having issues. Hence the question.

Comment: @JHS did you found the solution to this question.